# Media Queries: execute when height AND width are a certain size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is there a way to, for example, change the background colour when the browser is dragged to a certain size (say 200px x 200px). I've got it to work when it's 200 width OR 200 height, but I want it to be so that it only changes when the browser is 200 width AND 200 height. How can I combine the two queries so that it's not an either or, but an and.

here's the code, I need to combine them into 1 query that works when BOTH demands are met.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) and (min-height: 490px) {
    p{
        color: red;
    }
    body{
        background-color: blue;
    }
@media screen and (max-width : 300px) and (min-width: 290px) {
    p{
        color: yellow;
    }
    body{
        background-color: green;
    }
```

Hope that's clear,
Many thanks in advance

Comment: "I've got it to work when it's 200 width OR 200 height" What's the code?

Comment: your css isn't valid ;) and I wrote the same answer below :D too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to combine the queries with `and`. I've created a fiddle for you here http://jsfiddle.net/HChTD/

**Update**

Here is the between a range example: http://jsfiddle.net/HChTD/1/

Comment: fantastic! How can I tweak your query so that there's a small opportunity for it to work. Eg: box goes blue ONLY when the browser is between 480-490px width AND 480-490px height. So the user would have to move their browser to quite a specific size for it to work.

Comment: You are the best! I just can't figure out why I couldn't get it to work myself, is the order in the query important? Yours goes width, height, width, height - whereas when I tried it I did height, height, width, width. In any case it works perfectly so thank you so much!

Comment: I can't really tell if the order matters, but I don't think so ;)